# How to make a prefix.pch file for a duplicated target

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I just duplicated my target of my game to create a lite version. I want to define in the prefix.pch of the lite version that it is the lite version. The only problem is I have a prefix.pch file for my main target but not for the new one. Also in the new target, the prefix header is listed as the main targets prefix.pch. How do I create a new one? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

1. Copy your prefix.pch and rename it
2. Select your project file in "Project navigator"
3. Select your new target and go to "Build settings"
4. Search option called "GCC_PREFIX_HEADER" and set its value to your copied .PCH name

From now your copied .PCH will be used with your second target.

Comment: Is it possible to reference a prefix header from another target (folder)? I'd like to use the same prefix header in all of my targets, but for some reason the "test" target's prefix header doesn't seem to be included when compiling.